# How to keep the app logged in unless the user forces log out

Tags: android

I'm learning android and I have created an app with register and login options. Now I need to configure it to keep the user logged unless he logs out.
I've been told to use Shared Preferences, so I have used this code, but it doesnt seem to be working, it still logs out after some minutes.

```
public class PreferenceData 
{
  static final String PREF_USER_ID = "user_logged_in";

  public static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(Context ctx) 
  {
     return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
  }

  public static void setUserLoggedIn(Context ctx, boolean userLoggedIn) 
  {
     Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(ctx).edit();
     editor.putBoolean(PREF_USER_ID, userLoggedIn);
     editor.commit();
  }

  public static boolean getUserLoggedIn(Context ctx) 
  {
     return getSharedPreferences(ctx).putBoolean(PREF_USER_ID);
  }
}
```

Should I add something to fix the problem?

Comment: What do you mean, after some minutes

Comment: Your last line should say `.getBoolean`, not `put`

Comment: In the emulator, if I leave the app to do something else, let's say go to the bathroom, and start using it again, the user is logged out so you have to login again. I'm not sure if there's a time counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem in last function. Please replace that function with below code. You were using wrong api to get value from shared prefs

```
public static boolean getUserLoggedIn(Context ctx) 
{
    return getSharedPreferences(ctx).getBoolean(PREF_USER_ID, false);
}
```

Comment: Checked the api, you're absolutely right. I'll test it so verify the change.